# Issues with getting depth point kinect v2

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

Im really new to using the kinect, so cut me some slack Please. Im trying to get the depth            point in a frame from a mouse click over the image.Im able to get the pixel (x,y) successfully. But when i try to get the depth from the specific point using this code Im getting some errors and I unsure why. The depthFrame and ColorFrame that im getting are stored in cvMats. Someone told me to use depthFrame.at and I cant find any info on it.

Also from the microsoft website this is the parameters i need to successfully get my needed values.

```
public void MapDepthPointsToCameraSpace (
         DepthSpacePoint[] depthPoints,
         UInt16[] depths,
         CameraSpacePoint[] cameraPoints
)
```

Do I just need to get the depthFrame and store it into an array of type Uint16?

> error C2974: 'cv::Mat::at' : invalid template argument for '_Tp', type expected

```
       // Get the depth at pixel (col, row) 
        UINT16 depth = depthFrame.at<depthFrame.type()>(rows,cols);

        // Create a DepthSpacePoint based on row, col
        DepthSpacePoint depthPoint = { 0 };
        depthPoint.X = static_cast<float>(origin.x); // u
        depthPoint.Y = static_cast<float>(origin.y); // v

         //CameraSpacePoint to store (X, Y, Z)
        CameraSpacePoint cameraPoint = { 0 };
         //Map the DepthSpacePoint to the CameraSpacePoint
        m_pCoordinateMapper->MapDepthPointToCameraSpace(depthPoint,depth,&cameraPoint);

        // Access X, Y, Z
        float x = static_cast<float>(cameraPoint.X);
        float y = static_cast<float>(cameraPoint.Y);
        float z = static_cast<float>(cameraPoint.Z);
```

Comment: you cannot determine the type at runtime in a template, so `depthFrame.at<depthFrame.type()>` won't work. stick to `depthFrame.at<ushort>` instead

Comment: also, your `MapDepthPointsToCameraSpace` seems to be c#, different pair of shoes.